# how to reload an ecto record?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this code to insert a record into the database. After doing this, I need to get the new record's id to pass to the client.

```
  msg_record = %Message{
    fromEmail: params["fromEmail"],
    body: params["body"],
    room: room_id
  }
  Repo.insert!(msg_record)
```

The problem is, after doing this `msg_record.id` is still null.

In Rails I would do `msg_record.reload.id` - is there some equivalent method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I didn't look well enough at the docs.

This is found in the [HexDocs on Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html):

> iex> weather = %Weather{temp_lo: 0, temp_hi: 23}
>
> iex> Repo.insert!(weather)
>
> After persisting weather to the database, it will return a new copy of %Weather{} with the primary key (the id) set. We can use this value to read a struct back from the repository:

So in my case, I can simply reassign the varaible:

```
msg_record = Repo.insert!(msg_record)
```